# How to zoom out on load for mkmapview in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, mkmapview

This code I have works for iOS 6 but doesn't seam to have an effect on iOS 7. How can I get it to work for iOS 7 when setting the span doesn't have an effect?

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D  ctrpoint = self.location.coordinate;


MapPoint *mp = [[MapPoint alloc] initWithCoordinate:ctrpoint title:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@",NSLocalizedString(@"Pin Name:", @"Pin Name:"),self.pin.name] subtitle:self.pin.cell];
[self.mapView addAnnotation:mp];



MKCoordinateSpan span;

span.latitudeDelta = 0.2;
span.longitudeDelta = 0.2;

MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.span = span;
region.center = self.location.coordinate;

[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

the proper way is to use the constant provided:

```
- (MKCoordinateRegion)regionForWorld {
    return MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(MKMapRectWorld);
}
```

so

```
- (void)zoomToWorldAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    MKCoordinateRegion region = [self regionForWorld];
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Assuming that self.mapView is already synthesised I would do something like this:

  ```
  MKCoordinateRegion region = [self.mapView regionThatFits:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([self.location.coordinate, 800, 800)];
  region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.2;
  region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.2;
  [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
  ```
- Please note that the 800 values in MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance are "CLLocationDistance latitudinalMeters" and "CLLocationDistance longitudinalMeters". You might have to change these depending on your map size and the zoom level you want.
- For the map point I would do something like this:

  ```
  MKPointAnnotation *mapPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
  [mapPoint setCoordinate:self.location.coordinate];
  [mapPoint setTitle:@"Your title"];
  [mapPoint setSubtitle:@"My subtitle"];
  [mapView addAnnotation:mapPoint];
  ```
- I have tested this in both iOS6 and iOS7 and can assure you it works just fine.